# Local Portscanner with Python

Tags: python, port

I've createt a Python Portscann that works fine with external Adresses.

First you write the IP/Domain, then the portrange and it scanns all Ports and says that they are opened or closed.

But I also want to scann local machines (127.0.0.1) but the only output I become ist that the Port is closed....

Heres my Code: (Its not a Server, its running on a normal machine)

```
import os
import socket
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import time

clear = lambda: os.system("cls")

remoteServer = input("Enter the IP or Domain to scan > ")
sport = input("Start Port > ")
eport = input("End Port > ")
clear()


# The Scan funktion
def pscann():
    try:
        for port in range(int(sport), int(eport) + 1):
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServer, port))
            if result == 0:
                print("[+] Port " + str(port) + " = [Open]")
            else:
                print("[-] Port " + str(port) + " = [Closed]")
            sock.close()
     except:
        print("\nScann failed!")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("false adress.\n")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("the program will be closed...")
        time.sleep(4)
        sys.exit(0)

z1 = datetime.now()

pscann()

z2 = datetime.now()

ztotal = z2 - z1

print("\nScann succsfully!\n")
time.sleep(2)
print("The scan took: " + str(ztotal))
```

Hope you understand my problem...

thx

Comment: Thong with a port scanner is you do not want it to exit on the first failed connect. The try should be inside the for loop, and the except should not exit but conitinue to try the next port

Comment: Thx that worked fine :)